# Looking for a way to remove an errant calendar from MS Project Professional 2013

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

I have a project file with a project calendar that shows up in the **Change Working Time** dialog box's **For Calendar** dropbox that is not being using in the project file. I've looked in the Calendar tab in Organizer, but cannot find the calendar in either the project specific or Global list of calendars. How can I find and delete this calendar from the project file?

Comment: Is it a Resource calendar? E.g. Do you have a resource with that same name?

Comment: No. That's the funny thing. It's a base calendar that I've made sure no resources are using. It sits in the dropbox, but I can't find it anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a Resource calendar, your project may be corrupted.

You can use VBA to delete calendars. Go to the VB Editor (Alt+F11), show the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) and type this, replacing  with the appropriate calendar name and press Enter:

```
ActiveProject.BaseCalendars("<bad calendar>").Delete
```

Comment: I see how this should work, but I get the error: Run-time error '1101': The argument is not valid. I have triple checked I'm putting the calendar name in correctly. It's acting like it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "View" tab and select "Resource Sheet" under the "Resource Views" section. There should be a list of the resources that you can delete. Once deleted, they should no longer appear in the dropdown box of calendars.